# Deleting a bucket on Amazon S3 AWS SDK for PHP - Version 3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see lots of tutorials even on Amazon to get this done.  I follow it but for some reason it doesn't work.

I can do the other command below that works great, but deleting a bucket is not working, with no output for errors.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$key = 'file.txt'; // filename
$bucket = 'BUCKETNAME';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'KEY',
        'secret' => 'SECRET'
    ]
]);


$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key
));
```

This works, but it isn't a delete command (GetObject) :

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'file.txt'
]);

$request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
echo $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

Comment: What are you asking?  Does [`$client->deleteBucket()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#deletebucket) not work?

Comment: It doesn't work, yet it seems like it should based on the documentation.

Comment: Okay, it *"doesn't work."  Can you be more specific?  Show the code, show the error, etc?

Comment: that's why I wrote "with no output for errors."  I have heard of a debug mode, but wasn't sure how to use it for delete.

Comment: You might try deleting a bucket that you don't own, such as my `sqlbot-public-test` bucket in us-east-1, to see if at least you get an error when permission is denied by S3.  You have my permission to try it if you wish.

Comment: $client->deleteBucket('sqlbot-public-test');  I tried it with an if statement, but nothing shows.  Do I need to 'use' a  different class?

Answer (score 2):

To delete a bucket:

```
// Delete the bucket
$client->deleteBucket(array('Bucket' => $bucket));
```

You are missing the array.

Here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#cleaning-up

Comment: What about deleting a file?  That's what I was aiming for.  I have (array()) in there.

Comment: You can find it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_deleteObject